# event onClicked doesn't work when I open browser action popup in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

following the `browserAction` [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), already exists an event listener when my browser action popup is clicked (opened).

> **onClicked**
>
> Fired when a browser action icon is clicked. Does not fire if the browser action has a popup.
>
> **addListener**
>
> chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function callback)

I loaded this event in a background script `events.js` from manifest

```
{
    ...
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["events.js"],
        "persistense": false
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

**events.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { console.log('popup clicked') });
```

`events.js` is loaded because I put this code and works it:

```
chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title: 'new title of my popup'});
```

But `onClicked` event listener doesn't works. Any idea to fire an event when popup is opened ?

Comment: Assuming you have `"browser_action"` in manifest.json and **don't** have "default_popup", see [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry I have a popup.html in manifest.json I updated the question

Comment: In that case onClicked is not fired just as the documentation says. Simply put the code in your popup.js which is loaded as a standard `<script src=popup.js></script>`. It'll run automatically every time the popup is shown.